# Which is the most permissive open-source license?

Tags: licensing

Which is the [most permissive open-source license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permissive_free_software_licence) available?

"Permissive" would be defined as "the minimal requirements about how the software can be redistributed".

Comment: *definitely* not GPL.

Comment: "[Public Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_domain_software)", I would expect.

Comment: "Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!"... you may also want to look at other posts that have asked the same question on here and stackoverflow.

Comment: Is there agreement on what "permissive" means?

Comment: of course not... that's why it's a subjective post (but the moderators don't agree, so argue away!)

Comment: there's no such thing as objective question, answer or anything

Comment: So is your question intentionally subjective to evoke a conversation about what is the most permissible license (based on the opinions of others)?

Comment: no, I was just saying that subjectivity is subjective...

Comment: I don't think this question is unsalvagable, but "permissive" should be defined. It generally means in regards to distrobution as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permissive_free_software_license) notes. If it's not too subjective for wikipedia I don't see how it can be too subjective for us.

Comment: [Unlicense](http://unlicense.org/). Also see [Licenses](https://choosealicense.com/licenses/)

Answer (score 35):

The [WTFPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTFPL) (Do What The Fuck You Want To Public License) :

> The WTFPL (Do What The Fuck You Want To Public License) is an
>   infrequently used, extremely permissive free software license. The
>   original Version 1.0 license, released March 2000, was written by
>   Banlu Kemiyatorn who used it for Window Maker artwork. Samuel "Sam"
>   Hocevar, a French programmer who was the Debian project leader from 17
>   April 2007 to 16 April 2008, wrote version 2.0. It allows for
>   redistribution and modification of the software under any
>   terms—licensees are encouraged to "do what the fuck [they] want to".
>   The license was approved as a GPL-compatible free software license by
>   the Free Software Foundation.

Comment: lol this is funny

Comment: I wonder if the OP also includes no protection from being sued in his meaning of permissive......

Comment: In legal terms is there any distinction whatsoever between WTFPL and making a work Public Domain?

Comment: @BenBrocka: Yes, of course there is. Copyright law exclusively reserves pretty much all rights to the copyright holder. (The exceptions are basically only cases were human or civil rights trump copyright, e.g. the right to make a parody or the right to quote small excerpts, both of which are essential for free speech.) The purpose of *any* copyright license is to give the user rights that he needs but wouldn't have under just copyright law. If a work is in the Public Domain, then it isn't copyrighted *at all*.

Comment: @BenBrocka: Another difference is that in many jurisdictions you *cannot* give up your copyright, i.e. you cannot put a work in the Public Domain. For example, in my country, putting a work in the Public Domain involves the rather painful and lengthy process of committing suicide and waiting 70 years. So, if you put a work in the Public Domain, I cannot use it in Germany: it is still copyrighted, because you cannot give up your copyright, and all rights are exclusively reserved to the copyright holder, because there is no license on it.

Comment: @BenBrocka: Of course, the act of declaring something to be in the Public Domain *may* be construed by the courts as an implicit blanket non-exclusive license to all rights. But then again, it may not. Just putting a very permissive license on it is *so* much clearer.

Comment: Many companies won't use WTFPL-licensed software due to its lack of a warranty disclaimer and vague (at least, possibly to a lawyer) rights grant.

Answer (score 11):

Between the two you listed MIT is much more permissive than GPL (or LGPL).

If you want even more permissive, there's always [Beerware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beerware) and as a side effect you might even get some free beer out of it.

Comment: I live in Brooklyn, a beer can **easily** cost 7-9 bucks at a bar.  Beerware could become the most expensive ware of my hobby-projects!

Comment: which could easily be solved by simply switching hobbies.  Have you considered playing hockey or R/C models?

Answer (score 6):

I believe that your question doesn't have a single answer because there are lots of different licenses. I use [the simplified BSD license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses#2-clause_license_.28.22Simplified_BSD_License.22_or_.22FreeBSD_License.22.29) in my projects which is very permissive.